# PHP class method not called, but printed instead

Tags: php, function, class, methods, instantiation

So I have a class View instantiated before as `$view` and call the method inside like this:

```
<? 
$view->head($css_includes,$js_includes,$page_description,$page_title,$page_keywords,(isset($add_to_head) ? $add_to_head : FALSE)); 
?>

 <body class="body-blue">
    <? include("view/ecommerce-ga.php");?>
    <? $nav_url = "view/navbar".(isset($version) ? "-".$version : '').".php"; ?>
    <? include($nav_url);?>

  <!-- Wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">
```

Instead of calling the method, it prints this on the screen.

```
head(); $view->head($css_includes,$js_includes,$page_description,$page_title,$page_keywords,(isset($add_to_head) ? $add_to_head : FALSE)); ?>
```

I cut only the important part. Below it are loaded HTML.

It works on the server but not in my local development, which is weird. How can I get the method to work?

Comment: Your PHP install does not have short_open_tag enabled so you cannot use `<?` instead of `<?php`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me!